# Can Visual Studio's Project-Templates use T4s?

Tags: visual-studio, t4, visual-studio-templates

I'm surprised to see no link between the 2. Am I wrong ?

I have some tt in a project template where I put $safeprojectname$ as filename to write and it doesn't seem to expand the tt file and create the cs file accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can use them.  Visual Studio recognizes files with a `.tt` extension as T4 template files and expands them appropriately.  Oleg Sych has a lot of very good information about them. [This one](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/how-to-create-a-simple-t4-template/) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you sure ? I have some tt in a project template where I put $safeprojectname$ as filename to write and it doesn't seem to expand the tt file and create the cs file accordingly.

Comment: @user310291, I originally thought you were simply asking if Visual Studio can use T4 files. I wasn't paying attention enough to the wording to notice that you were asking specifically about VS project templates.  In that case I believe the answer is "No, they are not related".  But I am not familiar with how project templates are implemented.  Thus, my answer is probably not the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two together. To get the custom tool set up, you need to do a little extra work in your .vstemplate file.

Here's the code from the standard TextTemplate itme template in VS 2010.
The VSDesigner wizard code sets up the custom tool propery on the item.

```
 <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.tt" ReplaceParameters="false">Prospective.CSharp.tt</ProjectItem>
    <CustomParameters>
      <CustomParameter Name="$itemproperties$" Value="CustomTool" />
      <CustomParameter Name="$CustomTool$" Value="TextTemplatingFileGenerator" />
    </CustomParameters>
  </TemplateContent>
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Microsoft.VSDesigner.ProjectWizard.ItemPropertyWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
```